# Does Xur stay in the tower until you log out?

Tags: destiny

Does his appearance link to your current session and when you logged in?

For example, if I log in while he's still at the Tower, go off and do some strikes until after the time he leaves, and travel back to the Tower, will he be gone?

Or would I have to log out and log in for him to leave? Hope I'm explaining things well enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He appears at *exactly* 1AM* PST on Friday, and leaves at *exactly* 1AM* PST on Sundays.  It does not matter what you are doing client side, he will disappear at this time.

[Watch him vanish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY08eITOUIw&t=10s).

He appears in the same fashion, but I could not find a good video that wasn't bloated with graphics/misinformation to link.

*It was 2 AM PDT when we were observing DST, so when the clocks move ahead an hour in the spring, the time will likely return to 2 AM PDT.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I wonder what happens if you're browsing his shop at exactly 1AM PST on a Sunday...

Comment: My guess is that it would just kick you out of the menu.

Comment: Unless time zones are weirder than I think, the word "exactly" here is not correct. During one of the first weeks in the game I sat down in front of him and he didn't leave until about 11 minutes past the hour. Perhaps they've become more stringent on the schedule since then though.

Comment: 1AM your time due to your regional server,

Comment: @lasse interesting, my knowledge is only from others testing it.

Comment: @Virusboy I listed 1AM PST as this is the timezone that Bungie is located in.  You'll have to convert to local time if you do not live on the west coast of the USA.

Answer (score 1):

I should **imagine** that he will not load into any Tower instances after his departure.

So if you went to do strikes, when you came back to Tower, you'd load into Tower and he would have left.

As for if you are in a Tower instance whilst he is there and waited with him past his leaving time, would he just vanish? <strike>you'd have to test that</strike> Yes he would.